# Joining three tables

Tags: join, sqlite

I have a question

Find the titles of all movies not reviewed by Chris Jackson

Where the relations are 3 
**movie(mID, title, year, director)**,
**reviewer(rID, name)**,
**rating(rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)**

I have tried this query so far. Any idea of how to improve it or what am I doing wrong?

`SELECT DISTINCT M.TITLE
FROM MOVIE AS M
JOIN RATING AS R ON R.mID = M.mID
WHERE R.rID NOT IN (SELECT Rating.rID FROM Rating JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID WHERE Reviewer.name = 'Chris Jackson');`

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: I'd do the join all together, and just do the not in for the name only, but yes what results are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is too complex; the join between `movie` and `rating` is not necessary because the movie ID is already directly available from the subquery.

Anyway, using subqueries instead of joins usually is easer:

First, these are all reviews by anyone named Chris Jackson:

```
SELECT *
FROM rating
WHERE rID IN (SELECT rID
              FROM reviewer
              WHERE name = 'Chris Jackson')
```

(If you know that there is only one Chris Jackson, use `WHERE rID = (SELECT ...` instead of `WHERE rID IN (SELECT ...`.)

Now you want all movies that do not have such a review:

```
SELECT title
FROM movie
WHERE mID NOT IN (SELECT mID
                  FROM rating
                  WHERE rID IN (SELECT rID
                                FROM reviewer
                                WHERE name = 'Chris Jackson'))
```

---

It would be possible to combine the two inner subqueries with a join:

```
SELECT title
FROM movie
WHERE mID NOT IN (SELECT rating.mID
                  FROM rating
                  JOIN reviewer USING (rID)
                  WHERE reviewer.name = 'Chris Jackson')
```

Comment: Wow! You made it look simple